# Accessing custom sessions

Tags: php

I have a page that creates different sessions depending on different users it renames the session file to fit that user

```
 session_name("name");
 session_start();
 //i then put in a variable in the session file
 $sn=$_POST["name"];
 $_SESSION['name'] = $sn;
```

now in another file I want to access the session with the session name I just created

```
 session_start(); 
 echo $_SESSION['name'];
```

but it just creates a new session file and says undefined variable `$_SESSION['name']`.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following

[Using session_name() in PHP - Cannot Access Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25438889/using-session-name-in-php-cannot-access-data#25439092)

TLDR: At each startup request time (as already mentioned) the session will be renamed to PHPSESSID unless you call session_name( 'fObj') before session_start() on every page